# Cart items gets disappeared Magento 2

Tags: session, cookies, cart, magento2

In magento 2, adding items to cart, after 30 minutes the cart items gets disappeared. But i don't want it to be disappeared. please help me solving this. Thanks.

Comment: please use **abandon** cart then it will remain in specified days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the customer is logged, the products will remain in the cart forever. Well...at least the customer goes to the checkout process.

For the guest users by default magento provides 24 mins. You can change the cookie life time from admin and you can get more info follow this site
[increase cookie life time](http://ka.lpe.sh/2014/09/02/magento-set-session-cookie-lifetime-1-day/).

Comment: Mohan thanks for your quick reply. I have done the same